# php change the array value

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have an Array like this

```
$first = array("10.2+6","5.3+2.2");
```

I want to convert it like this

```
$second = array("10+10+6","5+5+5+2+2");
```

I also want to print out this such as way
10
10
6
5
5
5
2
2

How can I do this?

Comment: I would be inclined to create a helper function which converts, e.g. `5.3` into `5+5+5`, and then simply iterate over the array.

Comment: I would like you to try first: 1. Fetch array value 2. Explode it 3. Fetch the decimal value....

Comment: no need really for regex, you could just explode with plus then explode it with dot, repeat, implode by plus twice again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$first = array("10.2+6", "5.3+2.2");

$second = preg_replace_callback('/\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\b/', function($m){
      $_r=$m[1]; for($i=1; $i<$m[2]; $i++) $_r .= '+' . $m[1] ; return $_r; }, $first);

print_r($second);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10+10+6
    [1] => 5+5+5+2+2
)
```

We use this regex `/\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\b/` where we match digits before and after DOT separately and capture them in 2 captured groups. Then in callback function we loop through 2nd captured group and construct our output by appending `+` and 1st captured group.

Comment: ooh, I like this, have never seen this before! very cool, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Oh, it's great. This code works properly. Have there any other way without regex to solve this problem.

Comment: This is the shortest possible and simplest solution for this problem. Avoiding regex will make this code very complex

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions and various functions. There are many ways to accomplish what you're asking, and this is just one of them. I'm sure this could even be improved upon, but here it is:

```
$first = array("10.2+5","5.3+2.2");
$second = array();
$pattern = '/(\d+)\.(\d)/';
foreach($first as $item){
    $parts = explode('+',$item);
    $str = '';
    foreach($parts as $part){
        if(strlen($str)>0) $str .= '+';
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $part, $matches)){
            $str .= implode("+", array_fill(0,$matches[2][$i], $matches[1][$i]));
        }else{
            $str .=  $part;
        }
    }
    $second[] = $str;
}
print_r($second);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10+10+5
    [1] => 5+5+5+2+2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php

 $first = array("10.2+5","5.3+2");
    foreach($first as $term)
    {
         $second="";
              $a=explode("+", $term);
              $b=explode(".", $a[0]);
              $c=$b[0];
              for ($i=0;$i<$b[1];$i++)
                    $second=$second.$c."+";
              echo $second.$a[1]."+";

    }         
 ?>
```

Comment: You should test before you post. This does not work as it is. http://ideone.com/0sWwPZ

Comment: Whats wrong with you? the code is working fine(check your link).. it is just a logic that he can use to find the solution.

Comment: this is your output: `10+10+2+5+5+5+5+3+2+` how do you figure that that is correct?

Comment: according to the sample input that i given in my code ( array("10.2+5","5.3+2"); ) the output is correct only except one additional '+' symbol at the end.. i told him to use the logic..not the exact one .ok ?

Comment: Your output is not correct. There should not be a 2 after the 10 and there should not be a 3 anywhere.

Comment: ElefantPhace is right. Thanks to both of you for trying to help me.